# Variant is null! cannot invoke error in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

XML File Used:

```
    <!--
       The profile service
       $Id: profile.xml 89131 2009-05-19 20:18:52Z scott.stark@jboss.org $
    -->
    <deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0">

        <classloader><inject bean="profile-classloader:0.0.0" /></classloader>

        <classloader name="profile-classloader" xmlns="urn:jboss:classloader:1.0" export-all="NON_EMPTY" import-all="true">
            <root>${jboss.lib.url}jboss-profileservice-spi.jar</root>
        </classloader>

        <!-- 
            The profile configuration
            This contains required properties:
                The uri to jboss-service.xml.
                The uri to the deployers folder.
                A list of uris to deploy folders. -->
        <bean name="BootstrapProfileFactory" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.StaticProfileFactory">
          <property name="bindingsURI">${jboss.server.home.url}conf/bindingservice.beans</property>
          <property name="bootstrapURI">${jboss.server.home.url}conf/jboss-service.xml</property>
            <property name="deployersURI">${jboss.server.home.url}deployers</property>
            <property name="applicationURIs">
                <list elementClass="java.net.URI">
                <value>${jboss.server.home.url}deploy</value> 
                <value> </value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="attachmentStoreRoot">${jboss.server.data.dir}/attachments</property>
            <property name="profileFactory"><inject bean="ProfileFactory" /></property>
        </bean>

        <!--  The default profile key -->
        <bean name="DefaultProfileKey" class="org.jboss.profileservice.spi.ProfileKey">
            <constructor><parameter>${jboss.server.name}</parameter></constructor>
        </bean>

        <!-- The ProfileService -->
        <bean name="ProfileService" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService">
            <constructor><parameter><inject bean="jboss.kernel:service=KernelController" /></parameter></constructor>
            <property name="deployer"><inject bean="ProfileServiceDeployer" /></property>
            <property name="defaultProfile"><inject bean="DefaultProfileKey" /></property>
        </bean>

        <!-- The Bootstrap implementation that loads the Profile from the ProfileService -->
        <bean name="ProfileServiceBootstrap" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap">
            <property name="profileKey"><inject bean="DefaultProfileKey" /></property>
            <property name="mainDeployer"><inject bean="MainDeployer" /></property>
            <property name="profileService"><inject bean="ProfileService" /></property>
            <property name="mof"><inject bean="ManagedObjectFactory" /></property>
            <property name="mgtDeploymentCreator"><inject bean="ManagedDeploymentCreator" /></property>
            <property name="bootstrapProfileFactory"><inject bean="BootstrapProfileFactory" /></property>
            <property name="configurator"><inject bean="jboss.kernel:service=Kernel" property="configurator"/></property>
        </bean>

        <!-- The profile factory -->
        <bean name="ProfileFactory" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.TypedProfileFactory">
            <!-- Accept any AbstractprofileFactory -->
            <incallback method="addProfileFactory" />
            <uncallback method="removeProfileFactory" />
        </bean>

        <!-- The profile repository factory -->
        <bean name="ProfileRepositoryFactory" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.TypedProfileRepository">
            <!-- Accept any DeploymentRepositoryFactory -->
            <incallback method="addRepositoryFactory" />
            <uncallback method="removeRepositoryFactory" />
        </bean>

      <!-- The structure modification cache and checker -->
      <bean name="StructureModCache" class="org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.structure.modified.DefaultStructureCache">
        <destroy method="flush"/>
      </bean>

      <!-- This just checks metadata locations -->
      <bean name="MetaDataStructureModificationChecker" class="org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.structure.modified.MetaDataStructureModificationChecker">
        <constructor>
          <parameter><inject bean="MainDeployer" /></parameter>
        </constructor>
        <property name="cache"><inject bean="StructureModCache" /></property>
        <property name="filter"><bean class="org.jboss.system.server.profile.basic.XmlIncludeVirtualFileFilter" /></property>
      </bean>

      <!-- Synchs modifed files -->
      <bean name="SynchAdapter" class="org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.structure.modified.OverrideSynchAdapter"/>

      <!-- We just visit wars, but exclude classes, lib, dev dirs -->
      <bean name="WebVisitorAttributes" class="org.jboss.system.server.profile.basic.IncludeExcludeVisitorAttributes">
        <constructor>
          <parameter>
            <set>
              <value>.war</value>
            </set>
          </parameter>
          <parameter>
            <set>
              <value>WEB-INF/classes</value>
              <value>WEB-INF/lib</value>
              <value>WEB-INF/dev</value>
            </set>
          </parameter>
        </constructor>
      </bean>

      <bean name="StructureModificationChecker" class="org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.structure.modified.SynchWrapperModificationChecker">
        <constructor>
          <parameter><inject bean="MetaDataStructureModificationChecker"/></parameter>
          <parameter><inject bean="SynchAdapter"/></parameter>
        </constructor>
        <property name="originalAttributes"><inject bean="WebVisitorAttributes"/></property>
        <property name="tempAttributes"><inject bean="WebVisitorAttributes"/></property>
      </bean>

        <bean name="BasicProfileFactory" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.BasicProfileFactory">
            <property name="profileRepository"><inject bean="ProfileRepositoryFactory" /></property>
        </bean>
        <bean name="FilteredProfileFactory" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.FilteredProfileFactory"/>

        <!-- The default deployment repository factory -->
        <bean name="DefaultDeploymentRepositoryFactory" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.DefaultDeploymentRepositoryFactory">
            <property name="deploymentFilter"><inject bean="DeploymentFilter" /></property>
            <property name="checker"><inject bean="StructureModificationChecker" /></property>
        </bean>

        <bean name="ComponentMapperRegistry"
            class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.persistence.component.ComponentMapperRegistry">
            <constructor factoryClass="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.persistence.component.ComponentMapperRegistry" factoryMethod="getInstance"/>
            <!-- Accept any AbstractprofileFactory -->
            <incallback method="addMapper" />
            <uncallback method="removeComponentMapper" />
        </bean>

        <!-- A persistence factory for creating the persisted format of ManagedComponents -->
        <bean name="PersistenceFactory" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.persistence.AbstractPersistenceFactory">
            <constructor><parameter><inject bean="ManagedObjectFactory" /></parameter></constructor>
            <!-- Accept any ComponentMapper -->
            <incallback method="addComponentMapper" />
            <uncallback method="removeComponentMapper" />
            <!-- Accept any ManagedObjectPersistencePlugin -->
            <incallback method="addPersistencePlugin" />
            <uncallback method="removePersistencePlugin" />
        </bean>

        <!-- The attachment store -->
        <bean name="AttachmentStore" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractAttachmentStore">
            <constructor><parameter class="java.io.File"><inject bean="BootstrapProfileFactory" property="attachmentStoreRoot" /></parameter></constructor>
            <property name="mainDeployer"><inject bean="MainDeployer" /></property>
            <property name="serializer"><inject bean="AttachmentsSerializer" /></property>
            <property name="persistenceFactory"><inject bean="PersistenceFactory" /></property>
        </bean>

        <bean name="AttachmentsSerializer" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.JAXBAttachmentSerializer">
            <constructor><parameter><inject bean="BootstrapProfileFactory" property="attachmentStoreRoot" /></parameter></constructor>
        </bean>

        <bean name="ProfileServiceDeployer" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter">
            <property name="mainDeployer"><inject bean="MainDeployer" /></property>
            <property name="attachmentStore"><inject bean="AttachmentStore" /></property>
        </bean>

        <bean name="ProfileServicePersistenceDeployer" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.persistence.deployer.ProfileServicePersistenceDeployer">
            <property name="persistenceFactory"><inject bean="PersistenceFactory" /></property>
            <property name="attachmentStore"><inject bean="AttachmentStore" /></property>
       </bean>

       <bean name="KernelDeploymentComponentMapper" class="org.jboss.deployers.plugins.managed.KernelDeploymentComponentMapper">
            <constructor><parameter><inject bean="PersistenceFactory" /></parameter></constructor>
            <!-- Register under the attachment interface name as well -->
            <install bean="ComponentMapperRegistry" method="addMapper">
                <parameter class="java.lang.String">org.jboss.kernel.spi.deployment.KernelDeployment</parameter>
                <parameter class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.persistence.component.ComponentMapper"><this/></parameter>
            </install>
            <uninstall bean="ComponentMapperRegistry" method="removeComponentMapper">
                <parameter class="java.lang.String">org.jboss.kernel.spi.deployment.KernelDeployment</parameter>
            </uninstall>
       </bean>
       <bean name="ServiceDeploymentComponentMapper" class="org.jboss.system.deployers.managed.ServiceDeploymentComponentMapper">
            <constructor><parameter><inject bean="PersistenceFactory" /></parameter></constructor>
       </bean>

        <!-- A filter for excluding files from the scanner -->
        <bean name="DeploymentFilter" class="org.jboss.virtual.plugins.vfs.helpers.ExtensibleFilter">
            <!-- Files starting with theses strings are ignored -->
            <property name="prefixes">#,%,\,,.,_$</property>
            <!-- Files ending with theses strings are ignored -->
            <property name="suffixes">#,$,%,~,\,v,.BAK,.bak,.old,.orig,.tmp,.rej,.sh</property>
            <!-- Files matching with theses strings are ignored -->
            <property name="matches">.make.state,.nse_depinfo,CVS,CVS.admin,RCS,RCSLOG,SCCS,TAGS,core,tags</property>
        </bean>

    </deployment>
```

Code Snippet:

```
procedure SaveAttributeValueToXML(const AFileName, APath,  
  AValue: string);
var
  XMLNode: Variant;
  XMLDocument: Variant; 
  ResultValue: String; 
begin
  XMLDocument := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
  try
    XMLDocument.async := False;
    XMLDocument.load(AFileName);
    if (XMLDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0) then
      MsgBox('The XML file could not be parsed. ' + 
        XMLDocument.parseError.reason, mbError, MB_OK)
    else
    begin
      XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
      XMLNode := XMLDocument.selectSingleNode(APath);
      ResultValue := XMLNode.text;
      XMLDocument.save(AFileName);
    end;
  except
    MsgBox('An error occured!' + #13#10 + GetExceptionMessage, 
      mbError, MB_OK);  
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  UnicodeStr: string;
  ANSIStr: AnsiString;
  serverAnsiStr: AnsiString;
  serverString: string;
  profileXmlAnsiStr: AnsiString;
  profileXmlString: string;
  jdkDir: string;
begin
  if  CurStep=ssDone then
    begin
         hibernateDir := MPFWDestDir + '\hpfw\portal.war\WEB-INF\classes\config\hibernate\hibernate.properties';
         LoadStringFromFile(hibernateDir, ANSIStr); 
         UnicodeStr := String(ANSIStr);
         StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, '$!JDBC_USERID!$', ConfigContinuedPage.Values[0], True); 
         StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, '$!JDBC_PASSWORD1!$', ConfigContinuedPage.Values[1], True); 
         StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, '$!JDBC_HPF_HOSTNAME!$', ConfigPage.Values[2], True); 
         SaveStringToFile(hibernateDir, AnsiString(UnicodeStr), False);
         serverXmlDir := JBossDestDir + '\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar\server.xml'; 
         LoadStringFromFile(serverXmlDir, serverAnsiStr);
         serverString := String(serverAnsiStr);
         StringChangeEx(serverString, '$!WEBSERVER_PORT!$', ConfigPage.Values[0], True);  
         SaveStringToFile(serverXmlDir, AnsiString(serverString), False); 
         profileXmlDir := 'C:\Jboss' + '\server\default\conf\bootstrap\profile.xml'; 
         LoadStringFromFile(profileXmlDir, profileXmlAnsiStr);
         profileXmlString := String(profileXmlAnsiStr);
         StringChangeEx(profileXmlString, '<value>', '<value> file:/' + MPFWDestDir + '/hpfw/</value>', True); 
         //LoadValueFromXML(profileXmlDir, '//settings/Mail/MailServer');
         SaveAttributeValueToXML(profileXmlDir, '//deployment/bean/property/list[@elementClass=''java.net.URI'']/value', 'C:\MPFW'); 
         jdkDir := 'C:\JBOSS\jdk1.7.0_11_64';
         if CompareText(checked, 'true') = 0 then
         begin
            DelTree(jdkDir, True, True, True);
         end                                
    end
end;
```

Question:
    Im getting a variant is null error on trying to save the data in blank  tag section of the xml file. Need to set a value to the empty value tag after ${jboss.server.home.url}deploy this tag. Please let me know what is wrong in the code.

Comment: I would suggest you focus on specific lines of code

Comment: You've dumped a bunch of code with no clear problem description (*trying to save the data in blank tag section*). What specific line of code is raising the exception, and what are the values of the variables that pertain to that line? Then identify the actual section of that wall of XML that you're trying to write to, and the specific values you're attempting to write. Expecting us to wade through all of that clutter to try and figure out what you're asking, what you might be doing, and where the problem might be located is simply unreasonable.

Comment: This was asked a [few days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31960951/960757) (reporting that my solution attempt didn't work). You missed to use namespaces. Try this http://pastebin.com/LG5rBmD0

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, so just leave my suggestion for you.

The error message is "Variant is null", you can check variant is null or not before doing the next step, just like you did for `XMLDocument`:

```
XMLDocument.load(AFileName);
if (XMLDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0) then
  MsgBox('The XML file could not be parsed. ' + XMLDocument.parseError.reason, mbError, MB_OK)
else
......
```

So, do a similar check for `XMLNode` before retrieving its text:

```
XMLNode := XMLDocument.selectSingleNode(APath);
if not (IDispatch(XMLNode) = nil) then
  ResultValue := XMLNode.text;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i needed for an ADORecordset after executing an SQLCommand.